# Chart command is not shown in VS2019 Toolbox

Tags: vb.net, charts, visual-studio-2019

I've been looking around for a while about this issue: I need to add to my Windows Forms App (VB.net - Framework 5.0) a chart but it's not shown in the VS2019 Toolbox. I've tried to reset the toolbox and to add the component but the chart command isn't available yet. How could I solve this issue?
Thanks all are gonna answer me. Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there's no `Chart` "command". It's a control.

As for the issue, there is no Framework 5.0. The last version of the .NET Framework is 4.8. .NET 5.0 is based on .NET Core. Everything in .NET Core had to be reimplemented from the ground up so, while the vast majority of what was available in .NET Framework is also available in .NET Core, there are some things that have not been migrated yet. According to the documentation, the `Chart` control is one of those things. If you want to use a `Chart` control, you'll have to target .NET Framework 4.8 or earlier. That would mean creating a new project, because there's no automatic conversion between .NET Core and .NET Framework or vice versa.

Comment: I created a new VB-Windows-Desktop project in VS2019 with target framework as .Net 3.1, but when I try to add "Chart" control in toolbox from System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting namespace, it gives "Make sure the controls to add are compatible with the current designer and .NET framework version"

Comment: @user3676305, there is no ".NET 3.1". There is .NET Core 3.1 and, as I already stated in my answer, the `Chart` control is not supported in .NET Core. It may be once .NET 6.0 is released but it is not in .NET 5.0 or .NET Core 3.1 or earlier. As I already stated in my answer, you need to target .NET Framework 4.8 or earlier. Create a new project that actually target .NET Framework rather than .NET Core. The project templates that target .NET Framework actually say so in the New Project window.

Answer (score 0):

For using the chart in .NET5.0 one can download Maikebing.System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization from the Nuget package.
Although for unknown reasons, after some time this control vanished from the toolbox of Visual Studio 2019!